# ReactJs infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass as props the state object as a property  for the child component SkiDayList to be used in a map method. It triggers an infinite loop. Please help

Below is the code:
***APP.js:***

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SkiDayCount from './SkyDayCount';
import SkiDayList from './SkiDayList';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
           allDays:
           [
             {
               resort: "Teton Village",
               date: "20/01/2018",
               powder: true,
               backcountry: false
             },
             {
               resort: "Rabbit Hill",
               date: "21/01/2018",
               powder: true,
               backcountry: false
             },
             {
               resort: "Jasper",
               date: "22/01/2018",
               powder: false,
               backcountry: true
             },
             {
               resort: "Banff",
               date: "23/01/2018",
               powder: false,
               backcountry: true
             }
           ]
         }
     }

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>I am App.js with the state in it</p>
      <p> {this.state.allDays[1]['resort']} </p>
      <SkiDayList days={this.state.allDays}/>

    </div>

  )
}
}
export default App;
```

***SkiDayList.js:***

```
import React from 'react';
import SkiDayRow from './SkiDayRow';
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types';
import App from './app';

const SkiDayList = (props) => (
  <div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Resort</th>
        <th>Powder</th>
        <th>Backcountry</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          {props.days.map((day,i) => {
            return (<SkiDayRow
                        key={i}
                        {...day}
              />)
          })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <App/>
  </div>

)

export default SkiDayList;
```

***SkiDayRow.js :***

```
 import React from 'react';
    
    const SkiDayRow = (props) => (
      <tr>
        <td>{props.date}</td>
        <td>{props.resort}</td>
        <td>{(props.powder)?"Yes":null}</td>
        <td>{(props.backcountry)?"Yes":null}</td>
      </tr>
    )
    export default SkiDayRow;
```

Comment: `this.state allDays` - you forgot a point inbetween.

Comment: fixed, but that doesn't solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You included `import App from './app';` in `SkiDayList.js` file. Again you included `import SkiDayList from './SkiDayList';` inside `App`. That created circular loading problem. It is a circular dependency. You need to do either way.